# Почему база mysql стала меньше?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Прелюдия:

> du -hs /var/lib/mysql/my_base
>
> 28G

Сделал дамп базы, дамп весит 11 гигов. Удивился, что мало. Дропнул базу, восстановил из бэкапа:

> du -hs /var/lib/mysql/my_base
>
> 22G

Половина таблиц Innodb, другая половина MyISAM. Вот и призадумался, почему так?

Comment: Восстановленная база не фрагментирована.

Comment: InnoDB при удалении данных не освобождает место. Поэтому, если вставить миллион записей по 100К каждая, а потом удалить все через `DELETE`, то база будет пустая, но весить при этом будет 100Г. В оправдание можно сказать, что потом mysql будет использовать уже занятое (но еще пустое) место до тех пор, пока пустое место будет присутствовать. Т.е. некоторое время база расти не будет. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944). Потому после восстановления база и меньше стала - место на диске выделялось только для существующих записей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с базой данные которые вы удаляете из таблиц на самом деле не удаляются из файла базы и места на диске не освобождают, а просто отмечаются как удаленные. Потом это место используется под новые данные.

Когда вы удалили всю базу и восстановили её из дампа - такой фрагментированности нет - в базе находятся только те данные которые реально присутствуют. Так что уменьшение объема базы после дампа-восстановления это нормально.